# Add html elements OOP style using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, append

Is there a way instead of doing something like this:

```
for (item in list){
  $("#myList").append("<option>" + list[item] + "</option>");
}
```

To instead do something like:

```
for (item in list){
   var option = new option(list[item]);
   $("#myList").add(option);
}
```

`myList` being a drop down selection in the html.  I know for this example it doesn't much matter, I'm just thinking if the thing that gets appended (the `<option>`) becomes more complicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Option` and **[`select.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#add%28%29)** (native functions):

```
var select = $("#myList")[0];
for(var item in list){
    var option = new Option(list[item]);
    select.add(option);
}
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation where I can read about the `Option`?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt See: [new Option()](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml#section2).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
var $opt;
for (item in list) {
    $opt = $('<option/>').text(list[item]).appendTo('#myList');
}
```

It's a clear, OOP-like, jQuery-like way of doing things, with the added benefit of producing a variable storing the new HTML element as a jQuery object, for further manipulation.

Comment: As a add-on for this, you can actually do $('<option>', {text:"some text", "class": "some class"})

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  I like the syntax of the other answer a little more, but I'll definitely keep this in the toolbox as well